# tensorflow serving impossible proto files structure for grpc interface

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to compile pb files for GRPC calls to Tensorflow Serving (in php, but the question is not PHP related)

The file [serving/tensorflow_serving/apis/predict.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/predict.proto) has:

```
import "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto";
import "tensorflow_serving/apis/model.proto";
```

However in a normal setup tensorflow and tensorflow serving are not located in a hierarchy that has a common folder from which the two import can work together.

Assuming that compiling the proto files to pb files for grpc keeps the hirarchy , it cannot work without locating tensorflow serving under /tensorflow/. What am I missing here?

What is the best practice in order to compile pb files for grpc client?

Another issue: if the pb files are created - they include the imports with same hirarchy so it will force the same folder structure on the client ??? this is against the meaning of GRPC which is isolation and seperation between the entities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about tensorflow, but i'm approaching the problem from a *just-another-protobuf-creation* point of view. Here https://github.com/tensorflow/serving i'm seeing both `tensorflow_serving` and a *submodule* `tensorflow` which is a root of your desired dependency (i.e. it has another `tensorflow` subfolder in it). So i guess that you either missed some configuration step, which would have copied the folder into right relative location, or you are running an incomplete/incorrect `protoc` command line, i.e. you are missing some `-I <path>`

Comment: Thanks Pavel ! I didnt notice it ! I think you're right. I'm using a prebuilt AMI which doesnt have this folder. and it was probably not built correctly.

Comment: Actually the solution above of adding the folder to the right location doesnt solve the problem. dependencies still don't match.

Comment: If `tensorflow_serving/apis/model.proto` matches but `tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto` does not, supposing that you do have checked out the `tensorflow` submodule, which should be next to the `tensorflow_serving` folder, then try adding `-I ./tensorflow` to your `protoc` invocation